# Why is my dictionary not being changed outside of my function

Tags: python, dictionary

Any changes that I make in *products* inside the function **changeproducts** is not being set outside of the function.

```
products = {
    "apple": {"price": 3.5, "stock": 134},
    "banana": {"price": 6.82, "stock": 52},
    "cake": {"price": 23, "stock": 5}
    }


def changeproducts():
    #operator enter new products
    items = input("Items: ").split()
    prices = map(float, input("Prices: ").split())
    stocks = map(int, input("Stocks: ").split())
    products = {
        item: {"price": price, "stock": stock} 
        for item, price, stock in zip(items, prices, stocks)
    }
    print (products)


changeproducts()
print(products)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python functions can't assign to variables in global scope by default, so it would be creating a new dictionary instead. Add `global products` to the top of the function:

```py
def changeproducts():
  global products
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773030/19860022) said, edits within a function only exist to that function or it's sub-functions. You can either use a global variable as suggested,

```
def changeproducts():
    global products
    ...
```

But you can also use parameters + return values instead

```
def changeproducts(func_products):
    #use `func_products` instead of `products`
    ... 
    return func_products

products = changeproducts(products)
print(products)
```

When `changeproducts` is called, you give it the value of `products`, which it saves as `func_products`. Then once the function code has finished, it gives `func_products` as it's return value. The return value is then saved into the `products` variable again

For more info, check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reassigning the value, you can simply modify the list by using its `update` method, so in `changeproducts` do:

```py
products.update(
    {
        item: {"price": price, "stock": stock}
        for item, price, stock in zip(items, prices, stocks)
    }
)
```